# Установка Android SDK (java.exe not found) при уже установленном JDK

Tags: android, android-studio, java, sdk

Всем привет,
Перед установкой Android SDK поставила JDK.
Проблема возникает при установке SDK, а именно:

Java SE Development kit (JDK) not found.
Error: Failed to find java.exe on the system

То есть запрашивает установку JDK при уже поставленном JDK
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое может быть решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Android Studio` насколько я знаю не нужно проводить установку `JDK`. Студия автоматически сама устанавливает `SDK`, что является тем самым `JDK` которое необходимо для полноценное работы студии, в указанную вами папку, это очень странно если честно. Просто я вот читаю по вашей тематике разные источники и там говорят, что Android Studio использует инструменты Java Develipment Kit в работе. До недавнего времени перед установкой Android Studio нужно было скачать и установить JDK с официального сайта Oracle. Сейчас такой необходимости нет, поскольку Android Studio уже содержит встроенный пакет инструментов JDK.

Итак что я вам могу посоветовать еще, во-первых удалите уже установленный `jdk`. Дальше я думаю что не помешает перезагрузить ваш компьютер. После этого, запустите установщик студии, и попробуйте установить `sdk`. Я вот например перед началом работы в студии никакого `jdk` не устанавливал.

Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог в решении вашей проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Андрей. Ваш ответ решил мою проблему) еще раз большое спасибо :)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста, был рад помочь)